# SQL Server error: the INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Noodle__NoodleNa__1BC821DD"

Tags: sql-server

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Noodle__NoodleNa__1BC821DD". The conflict occurred in database "Project2", table "dbo.Noodle", column 'NoodleName'.
> The statement has been terminated.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

My syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Noodle 
(
    NoodleID CHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY 
         CHECK (NoodleID LIKE 'NO[0-9][0-9][0-9]') NOT NULL,
    NoodleName VARCHAR(255) 
         CHECK (NoodleName LIKE '%Noodle'),
    NoodleType CHAR(5) 
         FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES NoodleType(NoodleTypeID) NOT NULL,
    NoodlePrice INTEGER 
         CHECK (NoodlePrice > 15000) NOT NULL
)
```

My insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO Noodle
VALUES ('NO001', 'Indomie', 'NT123', 20000)
```

Where is the problem and how to solve it?

Thank you

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags. And please note the code formatting options in the editor.

Comment: And the error is telling you exactly what is wrong `'Indomie'` does not meet the check constraint `NoodleName LIKE '%Noodle'`. And as I pointed out in your previous question, you should be listing the columns your are inserting into as part of your insert.

Comment: thank you so much this is for my project you very helpful and I'm sorry id my English not good because English is not my mother language

Comment: I would also recommend to give your `CHECK` and `FOREIGN KEY` constraints **explicit names** - to avoid those system-generated names like `CK__Noodle__NoodleNa__1BC821DD` which are just hard to understand.... Use `CONSTRAINT CHK_Noodle_Name CHECK (.....)` to give these constraints your own, more descriptive names

Comment: `INSERT INTO Noodle VALUES (...` And this is just a bad and lazy habit. Always supply the column list for an insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- This is failing as reported by you  CK__Noodle__NoodleNa__1BC821DD
INSERT INTO Noodle
VALUES ('NO001', 'Indomie', 'NT123', 20000)

-- WORKING FINE : NOT FAILING
INSERT INTO Noodle
VALUES ('NO001', 'Hakka_Noodle', 'NT123', 20000)
```

Please note you have added contraint to add the NoodleName which ends with Noodel but value you supplying 'Indomie' which does not end with 'Noodle' so its failing which is correct. Second insert works fine because i provided the Noodle name as 'Hakka_Noodle' which end with '%Noodle' so inserted the data.